# Multiple tmpfs entries in fstab

Tags: debian, fstab, tmpfs

I've got a system which needs to be read-only - therefore, I've added a number of `tmpfs` entries into `/etc/fstab`, such as:

```
tmpfs /var/lib/sudo    tmpfs  defaults 0 0
tmpfs /var/lib/systemd tmpfs  defaults 0 0
```

In this instance, is it possible to have a single entry:

```
tmpfs /var/lib         tmpfs  defaults 0 0
```

...which does away with needing to reference each folder (`sudo`, `systemd`) explicitly?

Comment: Only if literally everything else in `/var/lib` is meant to disappear at reboot-time.

Comment: @DopeGhoti please post that as an answer (after fleshing it out a little, of course).

Answer (score 3):

You *can* make a single `tmpfs` mounted at `/var/lib`, but consider first the ramifications (if you'll forgive the pun):

*Everything* under that directory will cease to exist at reboot- or shutdown-time.  On one of my systems, this includes system-critical directories for things including but not limited to:

- vim
- mysql
- PHP
- tomcat
- samba
- logrotate
- initramfs
- dhcp
- apt
- apache

If your system as part of its bootup regimen repopulates the *entire* contents of `/var/lib`, what you propose is feasible, but if and only if that is true.